# R convert matrix into table

Tags: r, matrix

there is a matrix:

```
mat<-matrix(0,ncol = 10, nrow = 5)
colnames(mat)<-c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","A10")
rownames(mat)<-c("ID_1", "ID_2", "ID_3", "ID_4", "ID_5")
mat[1,] <-c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
mat[2,]<-c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
mat[3,]<-c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0)
mat[4,]<-c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0)
mat[5,]<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
```

[image]

I want to convert this matrix into a table with three columns - "ID", "start" and "stop", where "start" is a column with the first value (1) in row "ID", "stop" is a column with the last value in the row. I would like to receive this output:

[image]

Could You please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using `dplyr`, converting the matrix to dataframe, convert rownames to column, get the data in long format, `filter` rows with `value = 1` and select `first` and  `last` column name for each `id`.

```
library(dplyr)

mat %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column('id') %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(start = first(name), stop = last(name))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  id    start stop 
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 ID_1  A3    A6   
#2 ID_2  A4    A6   
#3 ID_3  A4    A9   
#4 ID_4  A6    A9   
#5 ID_5  A7    A10
```

---

In base R and keeping `mat` as matrix :

```
t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) {
   inds <- which(x == 1)
   c(start = colnames(mat)[min(inds)], stop = colnames(mat)[max(inds)])
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `ties.method` argument in `max.col`. Use the result to subset the `colnames`.

```
data.frame(id = rownames(mat), 
           start = colnames(mat)[max.col(mat, "first")], 
           stop = colnames(mat)[max.col(mat, "last")])
#     id start stop
# 1 ID_1    A3   A6
# 2 ID_2    A4   A6
# 3 ID_3    A4   A9
# 4 ID_4    A6   A9
# 5 ID_5    A7  A10
```